# The line of code is not appearing in my email on Outlook desktop

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

So I'm working on an HTML email, and this line of code is not appearing when I send it to the desktop and mobile versions of Outlook. It appears fine on Outlook Web, Gmail, and Yahoo.

My code

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCodeBlock">
         <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner">
                     <br>
                      <table class="orange-line" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="75px" style="width: 50 !important;" align="center">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="orange-line" align="center" valign="top" width="75px" height="2px" style="background-color: #fa5528; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px;"></td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
                      </table>
                     <br>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem comes from the units used. In an HTML attribute, you must set a unitless value (like `width="75"`). However, in CSS, you must use a unit (like `style="width:50px !important"`). The following code works for me in the Outlooks on Windows.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCodeBlock">
 <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
     <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner">
             <br>
              <table class="orange-line" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="75" style="width: 50px !important;" align="center">
                <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td class="orange-line" align="center" valign="top" width="75" height="2" style="background-color: #fa5528; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px;"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
             <br>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

See screenshots on Email on Acid: https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/nqr3Xb3Vsp7cql9X3hGSLUEWNeZkX7wlV2KtOwM2vtQwk/list